# "Git" is not working as Desired

Tags: git

Assume that i've repo like this:

```
~/Desktop/git_repo
$ ls                                                                          
cover.jpg  cover_small.jpg  README.md

~/Desktop/git_repo on  master
$ git status                                                                     
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now i will add an new *branch*, and switch current branch to *new_branch*

```
~/Desktop/git_repo on  master
$ git branch new_branch                                                          

~/Desktop/git_repo on  master
$ git checkout new_branch                                                        
Switched to branch 'new_branch'

~/Desktop/git_repo on  new_branch
$ git status                                                                     
On branch new_branch
```

Let's see our files on *new_branch*:

```
~/Desktop/git_repo on  new_branch
$ ls                                                                             
cover.jpg  cover_small.jpg  README.md
```

Nice, it is expected. Now, let's remove **cover.jpg** on *new_branch* but NOT
commit it:

```
~/Desktop/git_repo on  new_branch
$ git rm cover.jpg                                                               
rm 'cover.jpg'

~/Desktop/git_repo on  new_branch!
$ ls                                                                             
cover_small.jpg  README.md

~/Desktop/git_repo on  new_branch!
$ git status                                                                     
On branch new_branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    cover.jpg
```

Okay, again it is expected. Now, let's switch branch to our *master* branch and list files. I expect that **cover.jpg** is contained:

```
~/Desktop/git_repo on  new_branch!
$ git checkout master                                                            
D   cover.jpg
Switched to branch 'master'

~/Desktop/git_repo on  master!
$ ls                                                                             
cover_small.jpg  README.md

~/Desktop/git_repo on  master!
$ git status                                                                     
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    cover.jpg
```

**What?** Why my *master* branch is effected from *new_branch*? What is my mistake? That's my question.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand.

You've only staged the deletion of that file, and since that file exists in both `master` and `new_branch`, Git assumes that it's fine to keep the change in its stage.

To make the change permanent to `new_branch`, you want to check it out again and **commit** the change.

Once you do that, then the commits between your two branches will be divergent.

Comment: Thanks, i think not a good design. Assume that, i make change in _new_branch_ and it is not completed. When i have to switch branch to _master_, i can not **commit** because th changes not completed. Only chance is **stash** before switch branch. But, in this time, all "stash"es are combined for all branches. In large projects it will be so complex, isnt it?

Comment: @geTRekt:  It really isn't.  It just takes time and practice to get used to the nuances of Git.  Commiting things should be routine.  Stashing them should be when you *must* change branches in a hurry.  It's all practice from there.

Comment: I see, then the rule is "_commit_  for every little change, don't stack at _stage_".. Thanks, so much.